# Reporting my own exceptions through ACRA

Tags: java, android, acra

Let's say I have something like this:

```
int zero = 1;
if (zero!=0) {
    // have ACRA handle this as an error with stack trace and show the value
    // of zero, but silently, without the app crashing or bothering the user
}
```

How could I do this? I need it because I've exhausted most proper crashes, but my app still has errors that do not cause crashes and it would be nice to use the same error reporting system for those kind of errors as well.

I figured out how to send the app's Logcat output as part of the error report, but that seems too much, I only need a few values, maybe a single string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As explained in the [ACRA advanced usage](https://github.com/ACRA/acra/wiki/AdvancedUsage#sending-reports-for-caught-exceptions-or-for-unexpected-application-state-without-any-exception), you can use [ErrorReporter.handleSilentException()](https://acra.googlecode.com/svn-history/r172/trunk/CrashReport/javadoc/org/acra/ErrorReporter.html#handleSilentException(java.lang.Throwable)) to send any abnormal state to ACRA without notifying the user. If you don't have a 'real' Exception to pass in as the parameter, you can either create your own (`new RuntimeException("zero!=0")`) or pass in `null` to use the default `new Exception("Report requested by developer")`.

Comment: Yes, great! So, I just use `ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new RuntimeException("whatever I want"))` and it won't crash the app?

Comment: Yep, it'll just send a report to ACRA without crashing or notifying the user.